# Apache2 Test failing

Tags: apache2

I am configuring [RT4](https://www.bestpractical.com/rt/) on Ubuntu 15.04 but I am getting errors. Below is the output of the error:

```
technical@rt:~$ systemctl status apache2.service -l
â apache2.service - LSB: Apache2 web server
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/init.d/apache2)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Wed 2016-01-13 14:31:48 CAT; 1min 22s ago
     Docs: man:systemd-sysv-generator(8)
  Process: 14059 ExecStop=/etc/init.d/apache2 stop (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 14569 ExecStart=/etc/init.d/apache2 start (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
```

---

```
Jan 13 14:31:48 rt apache2[14569]: *
Jan 13 14:31:48 rt apache2[14569]: * The apache2 configtest failed.
Jan 13 14:31:48 rt apache2[14569]: Output of config test was:
Jan 13 14:31:48 rt apache2[14569]: apache2: Syntax error on line 219 of /etc/apache2/apache2.conf: Syntax error on line 29 of /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf: Could not open configuration file /etc/request-tracker4/apache2-modperl2.conf: No such file or directory
Jan 13 14:31:48 rt apache2[14569]: Action 'configtest' failed.
Jan 13 14:31:48 rt apache2[14569]: The Apache error log may have more information.
Jan 13 14:31:48 rt systemd[1]: apache2.service: control process exited, code=exited status=1
Jan 13 14:31:48 rt systemd[1]: Failed to start LSB: Apache2 web server.
Jan 13 14:31:48 rt systemd[1]: Unit apache2.service entered failed state.
Jan 13 14:31:48 rt systemd[1]: apache2.service failed.
```

Please do assist

Answer (score 2):

The issue right now is a syntax errror in the file `/etc/apache2/apache2.conf` on line 219.

It seems like you reference to a partial configuration `/etc/request-tracker4/apache2-modperl2.conf`, which in fact doesn't exist. (`No such file or directory`)

To fix this issue, find out where this file is actually located and adjust the file path.

Comment: Hi Frdmn, i am faili to find the file, i tried this technical@rt:~$ sudo find -name apache2-modperl2.conf
technical@rt:~$ locate apache2-modperl2.conf

Comment: Edit: /etc/apache2/sites-available/default
...and paste above the last "</VirtualHost>" parameter:
Code:

Include /etc/request-tracker4/apache2-modperl2.conf
RedirectMatch ^/$ /rt

find the command that we used

Comment: we found the file technical@rt:~$ find . -name apache2*
./rt-4.2.12/t/data/configs/apache2.2+fastcgi.conf.in
./rt-4.2.12/t/data/configs/apache2.2+mod_perl.conf
./rt-4.2.12/t/data/configs/apache2.2+fastcgi.conf
./rt-4.2.12/t/data/configs/apache2.2+mod_perl.conf.in

Comment: Perhaps the file doesn't exist on your machine. Where do you have the installation instructions from? There you should also find said file which you try to include at the moment. 

Edit: I just found this - http://lists.bestpractical.com/pipermail/rt-users/2012-November/078425.html